# Best way to access nested data structures?

Tags: c++, performance, nested

I would like to know what the best way (performance wise) to access a large data structure is.
There are about hundred ways to do it but what is the most accessible for the compiler to optimize?

One can access a value by

```
foo[someindex].bar[indexlist[i].subelement[j]].baz[0]
```

or create some pointer aliases like

```
sometype_t* tmpfoo = &foo[someindex];
tmpfoo->bar[indexlist[i].subelement[j]].baz[0]
```

or create reference aliases like

```
sometype_t &tmpfoo = foo[someindex];
tmpfoo.bar[indexlist[i].subelement[j]].baz[0]
```

and so forth...

Comment: When you measured the difference, what did you find?

Comment: the first option was the slowest probably due to a lot of access operator calls.
the second was the best of those 3.

Comment: Please update your question to indicate that you already know the answer and that it's the second option.  Then, please, close the question since you already know the answer and don't need anything from us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a personal preference, I generally find it easier to read and understadn if there are fewer nested levels to traverse.  Thus, I tend to use the ...

```
SomeType  *pSomeType = &asManyLevelsAsItMakesSense[someIndex];
pSomeType->subSomeNestedLevels = ...;
```

I find this particularly useful when dealing with deep nested structures in loops.  Identify the invariant nested parts and hoist it out of the loop.

```
SomeType  *pSomeType = &...;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    pSomeType->field[i] = ...;
```

As always, it is worth your while to know your compiler and what it actually generates.  Sometimes you may be stuck with a compiler for your project that does no optimization at all and so little things like this can make a difference (but don't assume that it will).

Answer (score 5):

Premature optimization is the root of all evil.  Write clear code, if it's too slow, profile it and see where the time is spent and optimize there.

That being said, 99% chance that the compiler generates the same code for all three of those examples.

Answer (score 1):

All of the three you described here will compile (with a decent compiler) to the same thing.